# GridView scrolling ends at half the screen when translated

Tags: java, android, gridview, view, scroll

Whatever i do i cant get this to work. I have a method to set the layout for the header of the view (which really is the whole view)...

```
private KenBurnsSupportView mHeaderSupportView;
private View mHeader;

private int mMinHeaderHeight;
private int mHeaderHeight;
private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
private int mActionBarHeight;

private boolean mResised = false;

private void setHeader(View fragmentView) {
    mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_header_height);
    mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
    mActionBarHeight = mUtils.getActionBarHeight(mActionBarHeight);
    mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight + mActionBarHeight;
    mHeaderSupportView = (KenBurnsSupportView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.song_header_support_view);
    mHeader = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.song_header);
    mHeaderSupportView.setImageViews(mPlayList.getPlImageView(), mPlayList.getPlSongs().get(0).getmImageView());
}
```

This uses this view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/song_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:transitionName="MyTransition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
        android:id="@+id/pl_artwork"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_background"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary40Transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pl_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pl_title_str"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pl_artwork"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/song_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_height"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="none"/>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/pl_artwork"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"/>


    <com.android.APPPACKEGE.widgets.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/song_play_fab"
        widget:circle_icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        widget:circle_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <com.android.APPPACKEGE.ui.songheaderlib.KenBurnsSupportView
        android:id="@+id/song_header_support_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What ever i do i cant get the gridView to end its view at the bottom of the device :

![Scroll ends at somewhat half of the screen][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBKiA.gif

Here is the onScroll part where all of it happens:

```
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int   visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int scrollY = mUtils.getScrollY(view, mHeaderHeight);
    ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mHeader, Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
```

And heres the getScrollY method:

```
 public int getScrollY(AbsListView view, int mHeaderHeight) {
    View c = view.getChildAt(0);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int top = c.getTop();

    int headerHeight = 0;
    if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
        headerHeight = mHeaderHeight;
    }

    return (-top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight) + 48;
}
```

I have tryed everything, even setting a fixed 770dp (570 screen size + the header 200dp size) on all the parents of the gridView. That didnt work...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your view gets translated above and never comes back to its original position, I think the problem is in the `ViewHelper.setTranslationY(....)` in your onScroll method. Try changing translation value, and see corresponding results for better tracing the issue. Hope it helps...

Comment: You translate all content in song_header. You should NOT do this, because grid view also will be translate. Try to take away grid view from header and translate without it.

Comment: I did try taking grid view out of the song_header, but when i do that, the grid view it self doesnt get translated (it doesnt move up with the header) it stays in the same place.

Comment: did you find solution @OliverTasevski